# Dickey-Fuller test in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to figure out exactly what the following expression means:

## Perform Dickey-Fuller test:

```
print 'Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:'
dftest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag='AIC')
dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
for key,value in dftest[4].items():
    dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
print dfoutput
```

More specifically what does this [0:4] represent?

Comment: `[0:4]` will give the first four items of `dftest`. It's called the slice notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not sure exactly what kind of variable `dftest` is but ill go through each variable so you might get a better understanding of `[0:4]`

Suppose you had an array like `array = [1,2,3,4,5]` and you did `print(array[0:2])` this will print `[1,2]`

On the other hand you could have a string which could be `word = "awesomeness"` and when you print `print(word[2:6])` you will get `esom` hope this helped!:)

Comment: The population size is 144 variables. Why would I only be taking the slice of the of the first 4 variables.
This is where I took the initial code from: http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python

Comment: @edost4 The dftest variable contains the results of the Dickey Fuller test which tests for a unit root in the sample. If rejected, it basically means that the given sequence, which is a time series, is stationary. The version implemented by the library returns several indicators (value of the test statistic, p-value, critical values, ...). By doing `dftest[0:4]`, you only get the first 4 indicators and omit some less relevant ones